# Div height to image height and image width to div width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div I use as a container and an image I use as a "background" (not literally, I was told I couldn't do this with background attribute) and then a content div:

**CSS**

```
#container {
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  min-width:100%;
}

.img1 {
  //DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE;
}

#content {
  //not important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <img class="img1" src="img.png"/>
    <div id="content"> Content </div>
</div>
```

I need the container div to be 100% screen width, and so the contained image, while both of them must have the image's resulting height (after the resizing from taking 100% screen width) (no stretching).
Any way to do that? I tried a lot of min-height and width combination but nothing worked so far.
I prefer CSS and HTML only solutions, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean, but how does this look: https://jsfiddle.net/b76fjtcv/

basically it's

```
.img1 {width: 100%;}
```

This [updated version of the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b76fjtcv/1/) also adds a max width to the img so it doesn't get too fuzzy. Just set the max-width of the .img1 to the image's full width.

Comment: Not sure you intended to do so but copy-pasting your code helped me finding out the problem was display:table (not sure why), so I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

What are both images? You only have one. look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp), you can use tables for formatting as well if you're not comfortable with div's.

Also, your image could be smaller or larger than the screen width, what then? Do you want scrolling or scaling?

Comment: WIth both I meant both the image and the #container division, and with in case of an image bigger than the screen (and this is the case since my image is 1080p) I need scaling.